# Print digits in decreasing fashion and then print factorials for number up to n

Tags: java, recursion

I want to take an integer n from the user and use it to print n-0, n-1, n-2, and so on down to zero (one number per line) and then back from from 0! to n!. Recursively. But I'm pretty much totally lost as my understanding of recursion is shoddy at best (being generous). Here's my meager code thus far:

```
static void p(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        System.out.println(n);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(n);
        p(n-1);
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Being at total loss for lack of understanding doesn't imply that others should do your homework.

Comment: Of course not. But a nudge in the right direction would be nice.

Comment: Fun, your almost there. Remember recursion is like a stack, when you make the call to `p(n-1)` your method pauses their and goes to the next one. When n=0 you break that recursion and start to come back out of that stack going backward. You just need 1 more line of code to finish it!

Comment: also you should read a java book first.

Comment: Your function boil down to: `System.out.println(n); if (n!=0) p(n-1);`.  Now ask yourself, is that you wanted.  Does that show any bit of effort?

Comment: If I were going to recursively do n! I'd return n * p(n-1). But that just gives me n!. Not n-1! or n-2! etc. Also, when I'm using void that won't work anyway.

Comment: So you want to count down the numbers, then print zero factorial to n-factorial up to n? These are two separate functions.

Comment: Yes. How do you combine recursive functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

didn't test it, but this should work.

```
static void p(int n)
{

    System.out.println(n);
    if (n > 0)
    {
        p(n-1);
    }
    System.out.println(n);

}
```

I'd recommend you to debug through the code to understandy, ***why*** this code works

UPDATE:

```
static int p(int n)
   {

    System.out.println(n);
    int newN = n;
    if (n > 0)
    {
        newN = n*p(n-1);
    }
    System.out.println(newN);
    return newN==0?1:newN;
}
```

Comment: Why a second println? That will produce unnecessary output.

Comment: You don't need the final println call there.

Comment: @BVB, JamesB: the second println is the second part of the question. CSpadawan wanted to count down and then up.

Comment: I wanted to print back up but with factorials. So 0! to n!. Normally I'd calculate them by returning n*p(n-1) but I'm not sure how to do that with void here.

Comment: @CSpadawan look at the update, i'll post in a second

Comment: @CSpadawan its impossible with void, except you recalculate n! in a loop again. but that would be nonsense

Comment: This prints 3,2,1,0,0,0,0,0 if n is 3

Comment: what's going on in the return of your update? I don't recognize the syntax

Comment: @CSpadawan: It's so it can increase the number. Otherwise, it will just print 0.

Comment: @CSpadawan this a inline if-else. if the condition (newN==0) is true, it returns 1, else newN

Comment: Fascinating. Thanks, everyone. Learning recursion has been frustrating for me but I'll keep hammering away at it. Last question: I'm using netbeans; how do I debug the code and what do I look for to see how it operates?

Comment: @CSpadawan: Your best bet to understand it is to write it out on paper.. you can see how it unrolls it self. Start with the number 3. It should take maybe twenty lines to map it all out. It's a small method anyways.

Comment: @CSpadawan i use Eclipse, but i found the following on google: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/debug-visual.html and fyi: i love Eclipse, feel free to give it a trial!